# Unable To Print Arrow Symbols using Python To Generate PHP/HTML File

Tags: php, html, python-3.x

A Python file outputs a web page using print(' '). However, it will not print out > (greater than) symbols when those symbols are inside  tags and are preceded with either a dash (->) or equal sign (=>). Totally destroys PDO SQL queries. When you replace them with `&gt;`, the browser simply does not display the page. Displaying the source in the browser shows (in the php sections):

> `"<?"`. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML.(XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML).

This is an issue with > (greater than) symbols only. < (less than) is rendered without issue.

Environment is Raspberry Pi, Buster (Deb 10). Apache2, PHP, MYSQL (Maria), Python3, php-mysql. Everything up-to-date.

On some builds, replacing all the `-> & => with -&gt; & =&gt;,` then running the script, then reverting back to `-> and =>` will actually produce working web pages. But why? And why does this trick not always work?

Comment: Before you think you have it all figured out. Turns out the > symbol in an html tag is also not recognized when produced by python inside a php inline script. However, as noted above, the less than symbol is 'printed'.

Comment: It's unclear what are you doing, but is seems to me that you are mixing PHP and HTML.

Comment: To get a solution here you'll need to show a specific print statement that gives you the wrong output from Python. And don't post the entire stack of from Raspberry Pi to Apache to SQL - the only relevant question here is whether your Python code prints the right string or not.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be something involving php and php-mysql. The fix (in this case) was to reinstall php (7.3). That created a lot of new config files. Then reinstall php-mysql. Finally, reboot. All works now

`#! /usr/bin/python3
print ('<?php ')
print ('some content here with a -> in it')
print (' ?>')`